# Proof needed for this exercise from "Linear Algebra Done Right"

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces and that $S\in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $T\in \mathcal{L}(U,V)$, where $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is the vector space of linear transformations from $X$ into $Y$. Prove that 
$$\dim \mathrm{null} (S\circ T) \leq \dim \mathrm{null} (S) + \dim \mathrm{null} (T).$$

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I literally have no idea how should I start.

Comment: taking basis is always a good start with finite-dimensional vector spaces

Answer (score 5):

Take any vector $u \in U$. Suppose $ST(u)=0$. Then $T(u)=0$ or $T(u) \ne 0$ and $S(T(u)) = 0$. That is: $u \in \operatorname{Null} T$ or $T(u) \in  \operatorname{Null} S$.

From the dimension theorem:
$$ \dim \operatorname{Null} ST \le \dim U = \dim \operatorname{Null}T + \dim T(U) $$
$$ \dim T(U) \le \dim V = \dim \operatorname{Null} S + \dim S(V)  $$

Combining these,
$$ \dim \operatorname{Null} ST \le \dim \operatorname{Null} T + \dim \operatorname{Null} S + \dim S(V) $$
Now we restrict to $Z = \operatorname{Null} ST \subset U$. Then
$$ S(T(Z)) = 0 $$
and
$$ \dim \operatorname{Null} ST = \dim Z = \dim \operatorname{Null}T + \dim T(Z) $$
$$ \dim T(Z) \le \dim \operatorname{Null} S + \dim S(T(Z))  $$

Combining these,
$$ \dim \operatorname{Null} ST \le \dim \operatorname{Null} T + \operatorname{Null} S $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For a linear mapping $L:V \mapsto W$,  $\dim V =  \dim \operatorname{null}  L + \dim \operatorname{range} L$. What happens when you take $V = \operatorname{null} ST$?

Comment: follow your thought (im not sure if misunderstand) here is what i thought  if u ∈ Null(ST),then (ST)u=0. So S(Tu)=0. So Tu ∈ Null(S). So every u that ∈ Null(ST) will also makes Tu ∈ Null(S). So Null(ST) ⊆ Null(S). So dim null (ST) ≤ dim null (S), and of course it follows that dim null (ST) ≤ dim null(T) + dim null (S)

Comment: @Hobbit6094 Careful - you can't have $\operatorname{Null}(ST)\subseteq\operatorname{Null}(S)$ because the first is a subspace of $U$ and the second is a subspace of $V$. But what you actually proved is that $T(\operatorname{Null}(ST))\subseteq\operatorname{Null}(S)$, which, if you think it through carefully and use the Rank-Nullity theorem, is enough to get what you want.

Comment: I've got !!!  dim null(ST)=dim null(T)+ dim T(null(ST)). because T(null(ST)) ⊆ Null(S), dim T(null(ST)) ≤ dim Null(S). therefore, dim null(ST)≤ dim null(T)+dim Null(S)